# How to create a click function for stop watch time tracker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to javascript and struggling big time. I am attempting to create a job time tracking tool that LOOKS like a counting up stopwatch. This is for a company used time tracking app that we are building a concept of before we build the real thing. Every stopwatch that's out there right now is basically used for tracking time and then throwing it out with the reset button.

All I have so far is the HTML and CSS for the time clock. I really don't even know where to start with the JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/jareddix/mkqy8ad5/19/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="time">
    <span id="hours">00</span> :
    <span id="minutes">00</span> :
    <span id="seconds">00</span>
      <div id="controls">
        <button id="start">Start</button>
        <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#time {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;


}
button:hover {
  background:   #20262E;
  cursor: crosshair;

}
#hours {
  color:red;

}
#minutes {
  color:blue;

}
#seconds {
  color:green;

}
```

Even guidance on where to start with JS would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to learn how to create a click event on the start and stop buttons to basically, create a newDate for each click that then subtract the first newDate from the second newDate and grabs the number of total milliseconds and translates it to seconds, minutes, and hours. Once I have that information it will need to be saved and sent to a db. I will cross that bridge when it comes later on.

Comment: This is a very big question. I would recommend reading through a tutorial on Javascript events. Here's an old lesson plan I co-wrote: https://github.com/ga-wdi-lessons/js-events-callbacks

Comment: You also might look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp